# If product sigma-field is countably generated, is each factor?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A)$ and $(Y,\mathcal B)$ be measurable spaces. Let $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ be the product sigma-field (the smallest sigma-field in which projections are measurable).

Suppose $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ is countably generated. Does it follow that $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are also countably generated?

I started by letting $C_1, C_2,...$ generate $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$. The obvious thing to claim is that $\pi_X(C_1), \pi_X(C_2),...$ generates $\mathcal A$, where $\pi_X$ is the projection onto $X$. Unfortunately, the measurability of $\pi_X$ doesn't imply that $\pi_X(C_i) \in \mathcal A$. But if this were the case, then we'd know that the sigma-field generated by $\pi_X(C_1), \pi_X(C_2),...$ is a subset of $\mathcal A$. I'm not sure how to attempt the reverse inclusion, but now I'm suspecting th result just isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $S \in \sigma \{T_i\}_{i \in I}$ then there exist a countable subfamily $(T_{i_n})$ such that $S \in \sigma \{T_{i_n}\}$. This general fact is proved by noting that the class of all sets $S$ satisfying this property is a sigma algebra containing each $T_i$.

Let $(C_n)$ generate the product sigma algebra. Then, by above result and the fact that the product sigma algebra is generated by measurable rectangles),  $C_n \in \sigma (A_{ni} \times B_{ni})_i$ for some countable families $(A_{ni}) \subset \mathcal A$  and $(B_{ni}) \subset \mathcal B$. For any set $A \in \mathcal A$ consider $A \times Y$ to show that $A \in \sigma (A_{ni})$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how the last step shows that $\mathcal A$ is countably generated. We just have that every $A \in \mathcal A$ is in some countably generated sub-algebra. Can you write down the generators of $\mathcal A$ explicitly?

Comment: @user435571 I have defined all the sets $A_{ni},B_{ni}$ in terms of the given sequence $(C_n)$. So these sets do not vary with $A$. So every set $A$ in the first sigma algebra belongs to the sigma algebra generated by the fixed countable family $(A_{ni}: i, n \geq 1)$.

Comment: I see. And the reasoning for the last step is $A \times Y \in \sigma(A_{ni} \times B_{ni})$ iff $A \times Y \in \sigma(A_{ni} \times Y)$ iff $A \in \sigma(A_{ni})$?

Comment: @user435571 Yes, that is right.